# Можно ли объявить функцию main как noexcept?

Tags: c++

Можно ли объявить функцию main как noexcept?

```
int main() noexcept {}
```

Компилируется нормально на ideone https://ideone.com/Pag79s

Comment: А чего вы хотите этим добиться?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

До C++17 было можно, начиная с C++17 - нельзя.

Но компиляторам разрешается поддерживать такое (как и любое другое 'нетрадиционное') объявление `main`.

> #### [[basic.start.main]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2)
>
> <sup>2</sup> ... An implementation shall allow both
>
> <sup>(2.1)</sup> — a function of () returning `int` and
>
> <sup>(2.2)</sup> — a function of (`int`, pointer to pointer to `char`) returning `int`
>
> as the type of `main` ([dcl.fct]).

Заметьте, написано *"as the type of `main`"*.

`noexcept` является частью типа функции (начиная с С++17), так что раз он не упоминается, то ставить его нельзя.

---

На англоSO есть схожий вопрос: [Can main() have an exception specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885942/can-main-have-an-exception-specification)